# Save different content to different files [Powershell]

Tags: xml, powershell, foreach

I need to place different texts in xml elements and save the content to different files, each text corresponds to a filename.

I'm a noob, my code：

```
$texts = (
    "Text1",
    "Text2",
    "Text3",
    ...
)

$savePaths = (
    "c:\foo\myfile1",
    "c:\foo\myfile2",
    "c:\foo\myfile3",
    ...
)

function MyFunction {
    param (
        $Text,
        $SavePath
    )
    $xml = [XDocument]::new(
        [XElement]::new("Item",
            [XAttribute]::new("version", "1"),
            [XElement]::new("text", $Text)
            )
        )
    foreach ($SavePath in $savePaths) {
    $xml.ToString() | Out-File ("$($SavePath.ToLower()).xml")
    }
}

foreach ($text in $texts) {MyFunction -Text $text -SavePath $savePath}
```

It created all the files but with the same content, how to fix? thanks in advance！

Comment: So you mean you want to write `Text1` to `c:\foo\myfile1` and `Text2` to `c:\foo\myfile2` an so on?

Comment: Is there a one-to-one correspondence beteween the elements of the arrays   `$texts` and `$SavePaths`? If so, within your function, don't loop through `$SsavePaths`, just save to the value coming in via the `$SavePath` parameter. Then, in your main ForEach, use `{MyFunction -Text $text -SavePath $savePaths[$texts.IndexOf($text)]}`.

Answer (score 0):

If those arrays `$texts` and `$savePaths` correspond, then why not use a template Here-String to create the xml file snippets?

```
$texts     = "Text1","Text2","Text3"
$savePaths = "c:\foo\myfile1","c:\foo\myfile2","c:\foo\myfile3"
# for safety, get the smallest item count of both arrays
$items = [math]::Min($texts.Count, $savePaths.Count)

# create a template xml as Here-String
# placeholder {0} will be filled in inside the loop
$xmlTemplate = @'
<Item version="1">
  <text>{0}</text>
</Item>
'@

# and loop through the items in the arrays to write the files
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $items; $i++) {
    $xmlTemplate -f $texts[$i] | Set-Content -Path ('{0}.xml' -f $savePaths[$i].ToLower()) -Encoding UTF8
}
```

---

It would be a lot better if you combine the texts and file paths in one Hashtable object like this:

```
$hash = @{
    "Text1" = "c:\foo\myfile1"
    "Text2" = "c:\foo\myfile2"
    "Text3" = "c:\foo\myfile3"
}
```

Then the loop could go like this:

```
# create a template xml as Here-String
# placeholder {0} will be filled in inside the loop
$xmlTemplate = @'
<Item version="1">
    <text>{0}</text>
</Item>
'@

$hash.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
    $xmlTemplate -f $_.Key | Set-Content -Path ('{0}.xml' -f $_.Value.ToLower()) -Encoding UTF8
}
```